# R Reference a cell within a user defined function

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R and really new to creating functions, but need to make some for others who don't use r to be able to use easily. I'm looking for a function that will allow me to reference a the top cell, or row of a column I've searched pretty hard but everything I've found seems to return errors. The function I need will subtract cells from the same column as the reference but moving down the column while the reference remains fixed. Code so far is:

```
df <- tibble(depth.along.core = 1:5, 
             Age.cal.BP = 1:5, 
             AFB = 1:5, 
             assumed.C = rep(0.5, 5))

Mega_Bog <- function(data) {
  require(dplyr)
  data %>% mutate(PCAR=((lead(depth.along.core) - depth.along.core )/(lead(Age.cal.BP) - Age.cal.BP))*AFBD*assumed.C*10000,
                  PCA_NCP = PCAR*(lead(Age.cal.BP)-Age.cal.BP), 
                  PCA_NCP[is.na(PCA_NCP)] <- 0, 
                  CCP_Bottom_Up = rev(cumsum(rev(PCA_NCP)))
                  CCP_Top_Down = CCP_Bottom_Up##Need cell reference here## -CCP_Bottom_Up)}
```

I know the is.na is a bit weird but it works, although I'm not sure why. The output I'm after will look like:
`CCP_Top_Down <- c(0,-1,-2,-3,-4)`

Thanks people

Comment: I find your question confusing. I dont see how adding a cell reference within CCP_Bottom_Up would result in the output you wish for. You can reference to a cell of a column using [ ], for example
df %>% mutate(CCP_Top_Down = depth.along.core[1] - depth.along.core)

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks, I'm a bit embaressed it was so simple, I searched everywhere. I'm afraid it's not giving me options to upvote or select your answer though.

Comment: Package `dplyr` also has a function `first()` that can be used: `df %>% mutate(CCP_Top_Down = first(depth.along.core) - depth.along.core)`.

Comment: @paul, glad it helped! No worries, I have also been stuck for hours on issues which were really simple in hindsight ;) Goodluck with your project.